# Winlogbeat or Filebeat для отправки текстовых логов в Logstash

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Всем привет, решили централизовать сбор логов, используя связку ELK, все логи с линукса без проблем отправляются с помощью filebeat, и абсолютно нормально обрабатываются и отображаются в elasticsearch. Проблема в том, что есть достаточно важный софт, на виндовс, который пишет свои логи в txt файл ( тот же teamwox например). Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу отправлять логи с файла, и корректно их обрабатывать и выводить в kibana. Лог допустим такого вида - дата, программа, статус, сообщение. Для линукса я ничего не настраивал, просто указал нужные папки логов и output для логстэша. Системные журналы уходят без проблем. Спасибо всем кто поможет!

ELK 7.3 ON CENTOS7

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем проблема. Вы установили logstash/filebeat на винду, пытались передавать логи в эластик, но ничего не получилось?

Comment: ELK установлено на cenos 7, отдельный сервер в локальной сети. С видовс сервера мне нужно передавать туда текстовый файл лога( не журнал ). Передавать я пытался на logstash, который бы уже кидал в эластик по тегам, на прямую не пробовал. Для передачи использовал filebeat и winlogbeat но безрезультатно